# ¿Cuántos usuarios de Cosmos usan stackoverflow?

Tags: discusión

Abro esta pregunta en stackoverflow para ir ampliando la comunidad **base100/cosmos**. Todas las preguntas que se creen propongo que sean con los tag `cosmos` y `base100`. Espero que esta pregunta/hilo sirva para ponernos en contacto (y que stackoverflow no me la cierre).

Si algún admin se topa con esta pregunta, por favor, queremos crear nuevas etiquetas para la comunidad de [Cosmos](http://www.base100.com/es/productos/cosmos01.html).

Comment: Si no me equivoco, no existe ni una sola pregunta sobre Cosmos en el sitio. Por qué crees que existe la necesidad de crear esa etiqueta? Cabe la posibilidad de que tengas alguna relación con esa empresa?

Comment: Hola David. En la pregunta enlazada, se explica cómo se crean las etiquetas. Yo podría crearlas ahora pero si no se realizan preguntas con ella, la etiqueta se auto-eliminará. Lo que sugiero es que, cuando hagas la pregunta sobre esa tecnologia, inmediatamente pulses en Reportar -> Se necesita la intervención de un moderador. Y ahi pedir que se cree la etiqueta para tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenidos. ¿Qué fue primero, la etiqueta o la pregunta? ¡La pregunta!, pero una pregunta que sea tema de SOes! -> [help/on-topic]

Comment: Hola a todos. Cosmos es un IDE de desarollo que lleva 25 años en el mercado. Somos muy pocos los que trabajamos con él comparado con otros entornos. La semana pasada tuvimos un Workshop con la empresa y acordamos crear una pequeña comunidad. Acordamos hacer uso de esta gran comunidad para publicar nuestras dudas y ayudarnos. Tomo nota sobre lo de reportar para añadir las etiquetas. Espero que la comunidad se anime y responda aquí y publique nuevas preguntas. Somos conscientes de que sólo así podremos hacer uso de stackoverflow. Edit: En absoluto consideréis esto como spam, por favor.

Comment: Gracias @DavidClothier por la aclaración. Nos parece estupendo que haya actividad de nuevas etiquetas y nuevos expertos. Solo recuerda leer bien el [tour] y [ask]. Un saludo ^^

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones. Por supuesto en [es.so] tiene cabida cualquier entorno relacionado con la programación. Como ya te han explicado, primero debe haber preguntas para que el tag permanezca, ya que si no es eliminado automáticamente. Perdona también la suspicacia, pero hemos tenido malas experiencias con compañías tratando de usar el sitio como atención al cliente. Suerte con la etiqueta y espero que mucha gente pueda recibir ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: @Pikoh Entiendo perfectamente las reticencias iniciales. No habrá ningún problema en ese sentido. La empresa tiene en su negocio una línea de soporte previo pago para incidencias sobre el producto. Lo que vamos a buscar aquí los usuarios es un lugar de contacto para preguntas técnicas y compartir la experiencia de muchos años. Estoy moviendo a algunos usuarios conocidos para que esto llegue a buen puerto y tengamos nuestro pequeño hueco aquí. Gracias por la confianza. Salu2.

Comment: En ese caso, bienvenidos y a ayudar lo máximo posible, que es de lo que se trata esto :)

Comment: Ya que vas a pedir que se abran etiquetas, podrias revisar tambien como funcionan las mismas, e ir preparando un texto descriptivo para cada una de ellas? esto es tambien muy importante, y dado que ninguno de nosotros parece conocer estas tecnologias, seria de vital importancia tambien que tengan a alguien preparado para decirnos si una pregunta es pertinente o no. Mientras cumpla con los estandares del sitio (sea sobre desarrollo, no sea sujeta a opiniones y demas) estaria bien vista.

Comment: Buenísima sugerencia. Tomo nota.

Comment: Hay algunas cosas que me preocupan de antemano: (1) ¿Qué tiene que ver la pregunta del título? (2) ¿Por qué 2 etiquetas para definir un producto? Una sola etiqueta por producto sería lo correcto. En todo caso, `[base100-cosmos]`. (3) Que quede claro que este no es un lugar donde enviar al soporte técnico gratuito (que pueden cerrarse), sino donde ver problemas habituales a la hora de programar... Me gustaría que estén familiarizados con el sitio antes que nada

Comment: Quizás sería más beneficioso que publiques otra pregunta (acá en Meta, no en el sitio principal), y que presentes lo que están por hacer... Es decir, no en una pregunta que busca "*cómo crear una etiqueta*" sino una que hable de sus próximos pasos y dé lugar a la discusión de la comunidad

Comment: @Mariano, efectivamente, con una etiqueta nos bastaría a la comunidad. Respecto a la pregunta del título, mi idea era que usuarios de stackoverflow (u otros nuevos) que usen el IDE entraran a la pregunta para que tuvieran constancia de la etiqueta y de que algunos usuarios estamos dispuestos a ayudar por aquí. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Para sacarnos las dudas, podrias publicar como respuesta a esta publicacion algunas preguntas tipo que se podrian llegar a hacer, para tener un feedback y ver si responden a los standares del sitio. Lo mas completas posibles (como si fueran publicaciones reales). (no es necesaria una pared de codigo, pero por ejemplo que diga aqui iria el codigo)

Comment: @Mariano David aún no tiene suficiente rep para publicar en Meta. Esta pregunta fue migrada del sitio principal.

Comment: @gbianchi David y los demás no podemos publicar respuestas a esta pregunta pues está cerrada.

Comment: De hecho, hay varios usuarios nuevos que se han registrado y no pueden responder ni valorar nada al no tener reputación. No veo la forma de arrancar desde cero, la verdad. O ya hay actividad, o es difícil que nuevos usuarios participen y usen la etiqueta que se ha comentado más arriba.

Comment: ahh mea culpa @Rubén tenes razon..

Comment: @DavidClothier para preguntar y responder no se necesita reputacion. si para votar positiva y negativamente. Y la reputacion justamente se gana preguntando y respondiendo.

Comment: Ok @gbianchi, lo comentaré con users menos experimentados. Respecto a lo que comentaste anteriormente de alguna pregunta ejemplo, en cuanto saque un hueco pongo algún caso práctico con su respuesta. Gracias por el interés.

Comment: Para eso existe el [tour] y [ask], justamente para que los usuarios sin experiencia aprendan.

Comment: @Rubén más motivos para que participe del sitio y se familiarice con el uso antes que nada

Comment: @Mariano como diría el Chavo del Ocho ¡Eso, eso, eso!